# Running Grunt task returns error

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs

I am currently trying to remove unused CSS from my CSS files using [this](http://grunt-tasks.com/grunt-purifycss/). For some reason I keep getting an error that I can't interpret:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
    purifycss: {
      options: {

      },
      target: {
        src: ['templates/**/*.html'], // Observe all html files
        css: ['static/css/main.css'], // Take all css files into consideration
        dest: 'static/css/newcss.css' // Write to this path
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['purifycss']);
};
```

When I run `grunt` in my command line I get:

```
>> TypeError: Cannot read property 'dependencies' of null
Warning: Task "default" not found. Used --force, continuing.

Done, but with warnings.
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you installed all dependencies with --save-dev?  If so, can you provide a listing of files and subdirectories under `template/` and `static/`.  This gruntfile works fine on my setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when your package.json is missing and you're using `load-grunt-tasks`. Run `npm init`, go through the prompts, then just check that the generated dependencies and devDependencies are what you expect.